# Error returns unable to cast object of type 'System.Decimal' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

returning an exception while passing dataset table for conversion to list.

```
//here i am passing dataset tables to FromDataRow   
var list = ClassA.FromDataRow(ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable());

//here is function implementation
    public class ClassA
    {
        public List<UserDesignation> UserDesigGrid { get; set; }

        public static ClassA FromDataRow(IEnumerable<DataRow> userDesignationDetails, IEnumerable<DataRow> userContactDeails, IEnumerable<DataRow> userCategoryDetails)
        {
            var classA = new ClassA
            {
                UserDesigGrid = userDesignationDetails.Select(r => new UserDesignation
                {
                    USER_ID = (int)r["USER_ID"],
                    DESIGNATION = (string)r["DESIGNATION"],
                    USER_TYPE = (string)r["LOCATION_TYPE"],
                    LOCATION = (string)r["LOCATION_ID_NAME"],
                    EFFECTIVE_FROM = (string)r["WEF_DATE"],
                    EFFECTIVE_TO = (string)r["WET_DATE"],

                }).ToList()           
             };
            return classA;
        }
    }
//property layer
 public class UserDesignation
    {
        public int USER_ID { get; set; }
        public string DESIGNATION { get; set; }
        public string USER_TYPE { get; set; }
        public string LOCATION { get; set; }
        public string EFFECTIVE_FROM { get; set; }
        public string EFFECTIVE_TO { get; set; }

    }
```

returning exception while converting

> "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Decimal' to type
>   'System.String'"

Comment: The error seems pretty self explanitory. One of the fields is a decimal that you are trying to explicitly cast to a string. Try and use r["DESIGNATION"].ToString ()

Comment: Try to use `ToString()` method instead of casting. In addition, it should be checked null value.

Comment: Alternatively, use `decimal` as the type of the property instead of `string`... and I'd strongly urge you to follow .NET naming conventions at the same time.

Comment: my table does not contain decimal value but also i receive this error

Comment: solved thanx my dear friends

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no implicit or explicit conversion from decimal to string. You could try:

```
string yourString = a.ToString();
```

where a is the decimal variable.